# TCL loop through multi dim array with stride

Tags: arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, tcl

I've got a 2-dim TCL array and seek an efficient way to loop through it. The array will have missing entries. I wish to loop through the array in two nested `foreach` loops as I have to do some housekeeping and printing along the way. As there are entries missing I will use some `info exists` functionality in the core loop. For the first index I know the key names and can give the list to the outer loop. But for the inner loop I have come up with no other way than using `array names -glob` However that return the compound index (TCL doesn't really know multi-dim arrays). I am looking for the best way to chop up this compound index as if there would be a `-stride` or `-index` option as if it were `lsort`.

This is hypothetical non-working code (I know there is no `-index` option to `array namees`) that sort-of expresses what I am trying to do.

```
array set ar { x1,y1 v11 x1,y2 v12 x1,y3 v13
               x2,y1 v21           x2,y3 v13
               x3,y1 v31 x3,y2 v32 x3,y3 v33
               x4,y1 v41 x4,y2 v42 x4,y3 v43 }

foreach x { x1 x2 x3 x4 } {
  foreach y [ array names ar -glob ${x}* -index 1 ] {
    puts $y
  }
}
```

Expected output

```
y1
y2
y3
y1  \
y3  / => Note missing entry
y1
y2
y3
y1
y2
y3
```

Your feedback is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Seeing proposals using `split` is OK. I was wondering if I was missing an option of `array names` or maybe something that can be done with `foreach` to make this more stream lined.

I can propose my own solution which uses `split`.

```
foreach x { x1 x2 x3 x4 } {
  foreach yy [ array names ar -glob ${x}* ]  {
    set y [ lindex [ split $yy , ] 1 ]
    puts $y
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no striding because elements _really_ are in arbitrary order; Tcl reserves the right to reorder the elements any time it wishes. Use dictionary values to get a defined order (the insertion order).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get the lists of primary and secondary keys fairly easily:

```
# You might choose different sorting rules…
set xs [lsort -unique [lmap xy [array names ar] {
    lindex [split $xy ","] 0
}]]
set ys [lsort -unique [lmap xy [array names ar] {
    lindex [split $xy ","] 1
}]]
```

Then you can iterate over those easily with nested `foreach` loops, using `info exists` to handle the sparseness:

```
foreach x $xs {
    foreach y $ys {
        if {[info exists ar($x,$y)]} {
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

Not on 8.6 yet? (Get with the programme!) You can collect the `xs` and `ys` like this:

```
set xs {}
set ys {}
foreach xy [array names ar] {
    lassign [split $xy ","] x y
    lappend xs $x
    lappend ys $y
}
set xs [lsort -unique $xs]
set ys [lsort -unique $ys]
```